Fetching Saved Posts from LinkedIn Using APIs
I am building a Java application for learning purposes, and I want to fetch saved posts from my LinkedIn profile.
My questions are:

Is there an official API to access a user's saved posts?
If not, are there any alternative approaches within LinkedIn's guidelines that I can use to achieve this?

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions. Thank you!
I've explored the LinkedIn API documentation, but I couldn't find an endpoint to retrieve saved posts.
